# Get a specific row and column value ascii file Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file like this:

```
A   B      C  D E  F G     H   I
1   105.28 1 22 84 2 10.55 21  2
2   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
3   150.23 3 78 22 0 12.02 11  0
4   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
5   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
6   357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
...
17000 357.01 0 32 34 1 11.43 28  1
```

from which I want to get a specific value (like 105.28) based on the row value (1) and the column value (2). How do I do this? I have googled, but not found any solution. It might just be that I am stupid, but I would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: assuming your file is A, `A(1,2)`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to first open up the file, then use [`fgetl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read the first line so we can analyze how many headers there are, ultimately leading to how many columns there are.  Make sure you use [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) to remove leading and trailing whitespace.  I will assume that each column header has no spaces.  We can use [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to split up the line into separate strings ignoring multiple whitespaces and we simply count how many of these there are.  Next, use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the rest of the file, specifying that you have as many floating point numbers as we have headers per row.  You can use [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to help you define this.  Because there are multiple white spaces between numbers, we need to make sure `textscan` ignores these and treats them as single spaces.  Once you're done, `textscan` will return a cell array of columns of data.  You should combine all of these with [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to get a numeric array, and then you can access the first row and second column.  Make sure you close the file after by [`fclose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html).

Assuming your file is called `text.txt`, do something like this:

```
% Open up the file
f = fopen('text.txt', 'r');

% Get the first line
line = fgetl(f);

% Split up the line into separate headers
c = strsplit(strtrim(line), ' ', 'CollapseDelimiters', true);

% Create formatting string
formatter = repmat('%f', 1, numel(c));

% Read the rest of the file
chars = textscan(f, formatter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);

% Combine the cell array into a numeric array
out = cell2mat(chars);

% Close the file
fclose(f);
```

`out` contains the output, and with your example we get:

```
>> out

out =

    1.0000  105.2800    1.0000
    2.0000  357.0100         0
    3.0000  150.2300    3.0000
```

Finally to access the first row, second column just use normal indexing:

```
>> out(1,2)

ans =

  105.2800
```

Comment: Thank. I however get this:

Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 75)
            m{n} = cat(2,c{n,:});

Error in Berakningsmodeller (line 37)
out = cell2mat(chars);

Comment: @KGB91 Please post your actual file.  This worked with the above text file.  This is what happens when you post a simplified example which doesn't reflect what is actually your input (and also very frustrating for me).

Comment: I can't due to NDA. I have made up som numbers above to show how it works. But it is not symmetric. The real file has about 70 columns and 17000 rows.

Comment: When you say "not symmetric", are there certain columns that are blank? Can you update your post to show even a minimal example? The code is highly dependent on the file format.

Comment: this code should work for your file, you literally just need to add %f for each column you have, so 9 columns = %f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f or you can do it with `repmat` :D

Comment: @KGB91 I have edited.  You need to change the format specifier to adapt this to the number of columns in your text file. I've done this for you automatically now.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Can Matlab get the numbers of columns by itself so I do not have to do this manually? (I have different files with different number of columns, but with similar data)

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, I now see repmat :-) I'll try it out

Comment: @reyryeng now I get: "Error using fgets
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in fgetl (line 33)
[tline,lt] = fgets(fid);

Error in Berakningsmodeller (line 22)
line = fgetl(f);"

Comment: That's because the file doesn't exist.  Please change the first line of code to the name of your file.

Comment: @rayryeng yeah... thanks! The only problem it that out now i a vector:

 0.0000
    0.0001
         0
         0
    0.0001
    0.0000
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
    0.0220
    0.0005
    0.0003
         0
         0
         0
    0.0000
         0
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0020

Comment: This code works assuming the above structure.  I can't help you if you can't actually post the file. Sorry.

Comment: @rayryeng  Ok, thanks a lot anyway! :) I'll work with the code myself for a while

Comment: @KGB91 ah you accepted the answer! How did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: I did not yet, but I see that I just have to tweak the code a bit. Your answer is correct, I just have to tweak it a bit :-)